# awk print long hex overflow?

Tags: awk, hex

Recently, I read some hex data with 16 length, like `0x1000 0000 0000 0000`, but print out some strange thing when print 0xffff ffff ffff ffff

```
awk '{printf("0x\n", 0x1000000000000000)}'  output `0x1000000000000000`  ok.
```

But, instead with

16 f  `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xffffffffffffffff)}'`, output `0`

15 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffffff)}'`, output `1000000000000000` （14 0)

15 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffffff0)}'`, output `0`

14 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xffffffffffffff)}'`, output  `100000000000000`   (13 0)

14 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xffffffffffffff0)}'`, output  `100000000000000`  (14 0)

14 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xffffffffffffff00)}'`, output  `0`

13 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffff)}'`, output  `fffffffffffff` （13f）

13 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffff0)}'`, output  `fffffffffffff0` （13f）

13 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffff00)}'`, output  `fffffffffffff00` （13f）

13 f `awk '{printf("0x\n", 0xfffffffffffff000)}'`, output  `fffffffffffff000` （13f）

so 13f is ok, how to print 16f?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing long integers in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857866/printing-long-integers-in-awk)

Comment: This prints a lot of `0x`, so I suppose the format string just left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the format string in the `printf()` call. Note that `printf`works differently than `print`. I assume you see some random erratic behavior of the awk interpreter.

Another typical awk problem is that it typically uses double precision floating point numbers to represent all numeric value (also integers) so you would loose precision and get strange artifacts when you get near 64 bit. This depends on the actual awk implementation.

You are probably seeing a mixture of these two problems. I admit the rounding to 0 is bizarre.