# Hex to Dec conversion with printf in sh fail for more than 16 digits

Tags: shell, hex, decimal, sh, base-conversion

I only have shell available no bash, Perl, python etc.

Using `printf` small numbers work:

```
root@DD-WRT:/jffs# printf "%d\n", 0x15a
346
```

But large numbers fail.

```
root@DD-WRT:/jffs# printf "%d\n", 0x15abc12345afda325
sh: invalid number '0x15abc12345afda325'
0
```

Also is it possible to perform hexadecimal arithmetic for example Module using shell ?

Comment: 16 hex digits is equivalent to 64 bits. Larger number needs a wider or arbitrary precision type which no shells I know support. Who needs to do arbitrary-precision math with a shell?

Answer (score 1):

What shell is this? On Linux I see:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $((0x15abc12345afda325))'
6538120775109288741
```

wrong

```
$ dash -c 'echo $((0x15abc12345afda325))'
9223372036854775807
```

wrong

```
$ ksh -c 'echo $((0x15abc12345afda325))'
2.49848648488188404e+19
```

right, but wrong output format

```
$ ksh -c 'printf "%d\n" $((0x15abc12345afda325))'
ksh: printf: warning: 2.49848648488188404e+19: overflow exception
9223372036854775807
$ ksh -c 'printf "%.0f\n" $((0x15abc12345afda325))'
24984864848818840399
```

GNU awk

```
$ gawk -v n=0x15abc12345afda325 'BEGIN {print strtonum(n)}'
24984864848818839552
$ gawk --bignum -v n=0x15abc12345afda325 'BEGIN {print strtonum(n)}'
24984864848818840357
```

Do you have `bc` available?

```
$ hex=15abc12345afda325
$ echo "ibase=16; $hex" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

hex values need to be in upper case?

```
$ echo "ibase=16; ${hex^^}" | bc
24984864848818840357
```

Hmm, different from ksh output. [WolframAlpha says `24984864848818840357`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0x15abc12345afda325)

---

I see busybox has `dc`, but sadly, it's crippled:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 16 i 15ABC12345AFDA325 p | dc
24984864848818840357
$ printf "%s\n" 16 i 15ABC12345AFDA325 p | busybox dc
dc: syntax error at 'i'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its on Busy box
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-05-31 11:07:38 CEST) built-in shell (ash)
No bc is not available nor ksh ,dash

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @HosamAmleh [Looks like you'd have to provide your own `printf` implementation](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2009-January/068147.html). `-fno-builtin-printf`

Comment: looks like there's some bug with gawk. I've checked and it produces different results in the last digits most of the time compared to bc and wolfram alpha. I don't know why you said `Hmm, different from ksh output` but it's actually the correct one. [*One is that letters inherent in hexadecimal numbers must always be upper case, because the bc software treats lower case letters as algebraic variables*](https://appuals.com/hex-calculator/)

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to write an **arbitrary-precision converter** from hexadecimal to decimal in pure sh (actually ash, since `busybox sh` runs the built-in ash). It needs a lot more effort than bash due to the limited set of features (no arrays) and "strange" errors without clear documentation (like spaces not allowed in expressions)

```
#!/bin/ash

obase=1000000000    # 1e9, the largest power of 10 that fits in int32_t
ibase=$((1 << 7*4)) # only 7 hex digits, because 0xFFFFFFFF > 1e9

inp="000000${1#0x}"                 # input value in $1 with optional 0x
inp=${inp:$((${#inp}%7)):${#inp}}   # pad the string length to a multiple of 7

carry=0
# workaround, since sh and ash don't support arrays
result0=0       # output digits will be stored in resultX variables in little endian
MSDindex=0      # index of the most significant digit in the result

print_result()
{
    eval echo -n \$result$MSDindex  # print MSD
    if [ $MSDindex -gt 0 ]; then    # print remaining digits
        for i in $(seq $((MSDindex-1)) -1 0); do eval printf "%09d" \$result$i; done
    fi
    echo
}

# Multiply a digit with the result
# $1 contains the value to multiply with the result array
mul()
{
    carry=0
    for i in $(seq 0 $MSDindex); do
        eval let res="$1\\*result$i+carry"
        eval let result$i=res%obase
        let carry=res/obase
    done

    while [ $carry -ne 0 ]; do
        let MSDindex=MSDindex+1
        eval let result$MSDindex=carry%obase
        let carry=carry/obase
    done
}

# Add a digit with the result
# $1 contains the digit to add with the array
add()
{
    eval let res=$1+result0
    eval let result0=res%obase
    let carry=res/obase

    i=1
    while [ $carry -ne 0 ]
    do
        eval let res=carry+result$i
        eval let result$i=res%obase
        let carry=res/obase
        if [ $i -gt $MSDindex ]; then MSDindex=$i; fi
        let i=i+1
    done
}

# main conversion loop
while [ -n "$inp" ]     # iterate through the hex digits, 7 at a time
do
    hexdigit=${inp:0:7}
    mul $ibase          # result = result*input_base+hexdigit
    add 0x$hexdigit

    if [ ${#inp} -gt 7 ]; then
        inp=${inp: $((7-${#inp}))}
    else
        unset inp
    fi
done

print_result
```

I checked with busybox in my Ubuntu and saw that it supports 64-bit arithmetic, therefore I need a 32-bit limb to avoid overflow when multiply. I choose the output base as `1 000 000 000` because it's the largest power of 10 that can be represented in a 32-bit int. Then the input base need to be smaller than the base (less carry handling needed), thus I choose 0x10000000, the largest power of 16 that's smaller than 1000000000

Of course if your busybox is so crippled that it doesn't support 64-bit int then you have to use base 0x1000 and process 3 hexadecimal digits at once

Confirmed with bc, the result is the same every time

```
$ v=15ABC12345AFDA325; busybox sh ./hex2dec.sh $v; echo "ibase=16; $v" | bc
24984864848818840357
24984864848818840357
$ v=2B37340113436BA5C23513A1231111C; busybox sh ./hex2dec.sh $v; echo "ibase=16; $v" | bc
3590214682278754501437472025955340572
3590214682278754501437472025955340572
$ v=60431BCD73610ADF2B37340113436BA5C23513A12311111111111;\
> busybox sh ./hex2dec.sh $v; echo "ibase=16; $v" | bc
2474996796503602902399592755755761709869730986038055786310078737
2474996796503602902399592755755761709869730986038055786310078737
```

Answer (score 0):

how many digits do u need ?

```
printf '0x15abc12345afda965317742584595757
          515927957157574571592325FFFFFFFFFFFF' | 

gawk -nMbe '$++NF = +$_'
```

> 

```
       0x15abc12345afda96531774258459575751
         5927957157574571592325FFFFFFFFFFFF 

642386077699778282185783828
 049060173534486064360167379
  481875931384718910679941119
```

- *Technically*, `gawk -nM '$++NF = +$_'` suffices;

  -- `-b` : for byte mode : to speed things up

  -- `-e` : just to be explicit about main
  code being sourced along the command line

And if you simply want the answer without the original input, even simpler :

> ```
>  gawk -nM '$_+=_'
> ```

```
642386077699778282185783828
 049060173534486064360167379
  481875931384718910679941119
```