# Awk muliplication gives me a different value than the normal multiplication of 2 numbers

Tags: shell, unix, awk

dummy.txt has the following data

```
3 19108601157904265
```

when I am trying to do arithmetic calculations using the below command

```
awk '{ print $1, ($1-1) * $2 }' dummy.txt
```

I am getting the answer as

```
3 38217202315808528
```

But it should be

```
3 38217202315808530
```

Normal command line calculation gives me expected value.

```
>a=2
>b=19108601157904265
>echo $(( a * b ))
>38217202315808530
```

Not sure why I am getting a lesser value than the actual multiplication.
Thanks in advance.

Solution given in the question "[Printing long integers in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857866/printing-long-integers-in-awk)" works if the gawk version is greater than 4.1 whereas my current current version of gawk is older one.

Comment: awk --bignum '{ print $1, ($1-1) * $2 }' dummy.txt solved the issue. --bignum does the work.

Comment: @RavinderSingh I have rolled back your edit of the deleted answer; merely deleting it should be sufficient, please don't also edit it to remove the answer attempt.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry I am not sure about that process. Why I am removing it because I understood requirement wrongly, so added that note in it. Thank you for letting me know. But 1 question, could you please do let me know why deleted answer can't be edited, if you don't mind please.

Comment: Deleting your answer it quite sufficient without also vandalizing it -- you just add another speed bump if someone wants to see what you actually did there, and having the deleted answer visible to 20k+ users potentially saves time from somebody who was drawing the same conclusion you did.