# convert hex to decimal with awk incorrect (with --non-decimal-data or strtonum)

Tags: awk

awk hex to decimal result is incorrect, not equal with bash/python

```sh
echo 0x06375FDFAE88312A |awk --non-decimal-data '{printf "%d\n",$1}'
```

or

```sh
echo 0x06375FDFAE88312A |awk '{printf "%d\n",strtonum($1)}'
```

the result is `447932102257160448`， but with python the result is `447932102257160490`

```py
python -c "print int('0x06375FDFAE88312A', 16)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `--bignum` option, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27670279/5407270) suggests. (Supported in gawk since version 4.1).

```
echo 0x06375FDFAE88312A |awk --bignum '{printf "%d\n",strtonum($1)}'

echo 0x06375FDFAE88312A |awk --bignum --non-decimal-data '{printf "%d\n",$1}'
```

The problem is that AWK typically uses double floating point number to represent numbers by default, so there is a limit on how many exact digits can be stored that way.